# Displaying Duplicate Records as One in Rails

Tags: activerecord

I have a table of sales information, each product has twelve records for each month of the year. The only unique value is the sale total.

```
    #<AccountMarginTarget id: 1, product_id: "123", sales: 2000>
    #<AccountMarginTarget id: 2, product_id: "123", sales: 50>
    #<AccountMarginTarget id: 2, product_id: "123", sales: 37>
    #<AccountMarginTarget id: 2, product_id: "22", sales: 47>
    #<AccountMarginTarget id: 2, product_id: "22", sales: 74>
```

I know I can retrieve consolodated data using .group, eg:

```
YearSales.group(:product_id).sum(:sale_total)
```

But when it comes to displaying all in the view, it's troublesome to have a list of 12 records. I've looked at `.join .group .uniq` etc. - but I'm still puzzled to as what the best method for only listing duplicates once?

Apologies for any naivety!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've figured this out and feel a little dumb as to how easy it was to achieve. As I'm a Jr I'd appreciate any improvements on the below :) I'll update as my I review my code.

As I have many duplicates in my table, first I need to single them out

```
unique_ids = @sale_records.map(&:product_id).uniq.map
```

then I iterate through the unique_id's and retrieve the first result from the database that matches it:

```
@unique_product_sale_records = unique_ids.collect.each do | unique_id |
  SalesRecord.where(product_id: unique_id).first
end
```